# How do I fix React rendering issues?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very simple component that fetches data and do some easy computation. Every time the page refreshes the component renders, the value will change. I have also tried clearing the cache thinking it might be an issue but it didn't solve the problem. Thank you for your help!

I have tried removing and I get a warning with a message suggesting to add `difference` but even without it, it still behaves the same on every single render.  I use `difference` value like this

**I have put the code on Sandbox to make easier to debug. Same problem still occurs on every other page refresh.**

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-cdn-q3gju?file=/src/Card.js

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please revise to be more specific about what's going wrong and what you expect to happen.

Comment: I guess you are having infinite loop. That is because you are updating the state (difference) inside useEffect. But difference is also a dependency for the useEffect to run, so every time it renders, it will render, run the effect, and all over again and again. I can imagine at least two solutions for that, please confirm if that's the problem.

Comment: @maxpsz Thank you but it doesn't resolve the problem. I have edited the question and add a link to the code to debug easier.

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem you are facing? Yes, the values are different in each render, because the api you are getting data from, always sends different values, it has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: @maxpsz but in the code I have already specified which data to fetch and change. Please have a look at the data.js file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Each state change generates the component rendering. You are listening to the "difference" variable change and changing it again with setDifference, creating a loop.

This

```
useEffect(()=>{
   setState(something)
},[state])
```

Use

```
useEffect(()=>{
   setState(something)
},[])
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't resolve the problem. I have edited the question and add a link to the code to make debugging easier.